# Python - How to get a specific value form Pandas DataFrame from CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, csv, timedate

I have problem with getting a specific value from DataFrame object.

1. My CVS file looks like:

```
domain1.com,1.1.1.1,2023-01-01,description 1
domain2.com,2.2.2.2,2023-02-23,,description 2
```

2. Next i read CSV using Pandas and Data Frame object

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('database\domain\ip.csv', sep = ',', header = None)

#headers 
dataset.columns = ['domain', 'ip', 'data', 'ASN']

#format column to datetime format from datetime library
dataset['data'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['data'], format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

3. Next i want check a specific value if existing in DataFrame

```
if((dataset["domain"] == 'domain2').any()):
```

4. I want get a data and I want compare this date to another:

```
a = dataset[dataset["domain"] == 'wp.pl.com']['data']
    
if (datetime.now() - a) > timedelta(days = 30):
   #something
```

But i got error:
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

If i change to: `a.any()` or `a.any()` i got another error:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'bool`

Anybody know how can i compare two dates?

Answer (score 0):

Try before to get both dates as strings and convert them to objects using
`datetime.strptime()`

For example:

```
date_a = '22-06-2023'
date_b = '23-06-2023'

date_a_object = datetime.strptime(date_a, '%d-%m-%Y')
date_b_object = datetime.strptime(date_b, '%d-%m-%Y')

# Do comparison, for example
if date_b_object > date_a_object:
    # some code
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but compare two dates is not a problem. My code works perfect if I replace variable "a" another date (for example datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 1) or datetime.strptime("2010-01-1", "%Y-%m-%d"). The problem is only when i try compare date and date form Data Frame object

Comment: Another thing is "datetime.strptime()" works for string not for series but a object "a" from the Data Frame is not a string (is a series).

Answer (score 0):

I think i got solution. It is not perfect, looks aful, but I tested it and it works:

```
aa = a.to_string().split(" ")
for x in aa:
   if(x.find("-") != -1):
       a = datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d")
```